# Indexing structures numpy arrays with nested flexible types (np.void type)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to index into a structured numpy array with a nested typing. For example,

```
a = np.array([((1.,2.),1),((2.,1.),2)], dtype=[('blah',[('beep','f'),('boop','f')]),('num','i')])
```

I can access `'beep'` and `'boop'` like this,

```
>>> a['blah'][['beep','boop']] 
array([(1., 2.), (2., 1.)], dtype=[('row', '<f4'), ('col', '<f4')])
```

but is there some way I can do this without first indexing 'blah' separately? For example, I would like to do

```
>>> a[['blah',['beep','boop']]]
```

but this returns,

```
<stdin>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

In general, I want to be able to index into an structured array like this for any possible type nesting without having any hard-coded knowledge about how deep the nesting is (or even if it's nested at all).

Comment: Not really.  I can imagine doing something elaborate, like using `arr.dtype.fields.names` to get the list of field names at one level, and then working your way down.  But there isn't any indexing shortcut that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest recursively exploring the dtype to get the column of interest.

This example examines each level of the dtype, and prints it if it find a column named either beep or boop.

```
def recursively_get_columns(array, path=()):
    names = array.dtype.names
    for name in names:
        col = array[name]
        is_simple = col.dtype.names is None
        new_path = path + (name,)
        if is_simple:
            yield new_path, array[name]
        else:
            yield from recursively_get_columns(col, new_path)
for path, col in recursively_get_columns(a):
    if path[-1] in ['beep', 'boop']:
        print(path, col)
```

Outputs:

```
('blah', 'beep') [1. 2.]
('blah', 'boop') [2. 1.]
```

Answer (score 2):

exploring `recfunctions`

https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.rec.html#module-numpy.lib.recfunctions

```
In [104]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf

In [105]: a = np.array([((1.,2.),1),((2.,1.),2)], dtype=[('blah',[('beep','f'),('boop','f')]),('num','i')])

In [106]: a.dtype
Out[106]: dtype([('blah', [('beep', '<f4'), ('boop', '<f4')]), ('num', '<i4')])

In [107]: rf.flatten_descr(a.dtype)
Out[107]: 
(('beep', dtype('float32')),
 ('boop', dtype('float32')),
 ('num', dtype('int32')))

In [108]: a.dtype.names
Out[108]: ('blah', 'num')


In [110]: rf.get_names(a.dtype)
Out[110]: (('blah', ('beep', 'boop')), 'num')

In [111]: rf.get_names_flat(a.dtype)
Out[111]: ('blah', 'beep', 'boop', 'num')
```

This isn't a heavily used library, written I think back in the days when `recarray` was more common.  Now we mostly use the `structured array` form, or pandas.  Mostly these functions explore the `dtype`, its `names`, and when making something new, create a 'blank', and copy data by field name.